# Why color doesn't looks same as texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I wasnt convinced that color is same as in UV image because the face is kinda looks bit of a gray. In Shade Node, I've connected Image Texture to Principled BSDF, however, without BSDF, the face doesn't looks great without BSDF.

[image]

[image]

[image: This is how its look in cycle render]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share the file?

Comment: @Moonboots
Uh, how I can pack them in here?

Comment: File > External Data > Pack Resources

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Base Color, which is OK, you have plugged your color texture into the subsurface strenght input, while you should have it plugged into the Subsurface Color input.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.
I've to plug image texture to Subsurface and Subsurface Color?

I did that.
https://imgur.com/a/M3kGoOO

Comment: In this last setup of yours, texture color is starting to appear, but the subsurface effect is still way too much, because the value of the image is controlling the strenght of the effect. Set a value of 0.1 as starting point. You can do it either unplugging the color ramp and setting manually 0.1, or clicking on the white color of the color ramp and taking it down to a dark grey (again, with a value about 0.1, as starting point, to be tweaked).